# HTML : Can anchor be clicked when it was disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML :   Can `<a>` be clicked when `<a>` was disabled ?

I got an error of repeat submit form.Then I disabled the Hyperlink which to submit the form when it was clicked,not function well.

So I changed hyperlink to `<button>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable onlick event on link:

```js
var validate = function() {

   // your code

   return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return validate();">Link</a>
```